# Was there always a beracha for Shabbat candles?

Tags: shabbat, history

The wikipedia entry for [Shabbat Candles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabbat_candles) says that:

> The first record of the complete text of the blessing is from the
>   Siddur of Rav Amram, written by Amram Gaon in the 9th century. He then
>   cites Talmudic sources that a blessing was mandatory.
>
> ...it has been argued that, in Europe, Jewish women lit Shabbat lamps without a blessing until the 11th century

Is there any further information regarding when a beracha was instituted to accompany the lighting of Shabbat candles and when such a practice began?

Comment: There's a strong conjecture that it was in response to the Karaites. (They sat in the dark on Shabbat based on their interpretation of the Torah, so the Gaonim instituted a blessing to remind mainstream Judaism that you *should* have a pre-lit fire in your house on Shabbat, and doing so is part of the observance.)

Comment: Check out Tosafot Shabbat 25b sv Chova who quote 'some' as holding that no blessing is recited

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/98488/759

Comment: thanks @JoelK, that Tosafot brings that Rav Amram, that he had the nusach "asher kidshanu" for lighting candles on shabbat.